# return a value from a service

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have a function and need that just return a value, The problem is that when I return by console I get the $$state and not the value that I need.

```
function getIdCategory(idItem, apiService)
{
    return apiService.request('POST', '/categories/view', idItem).then(
        function(response)
        {
            return response.data[0].id;
        }
    );
}
```

[image]

in this case just need the value 6.

Comment: What's the code snippet you print the log? I guess what you print is the promise object returned by getIdCategory.

Comment: is this -> console.log(getIdCategory(idItem, apiService));

Answer (score 0):

What you printed is the promise object returned by getIdCategory(). You could get the value like below:

```
getIdCategory(idItem, apiService).then(function(value) {
    console.log('value', value);
}, function(err) {
    // handle error
})
```

This is how you consume a promise object. You can google promise for more information about how to use it.